# How to run a normal C program using monit

Tags: linux, monit

I'm trying to monitor a normal C program in Monit, but I don't know how to run the program, what configuration should be set in the control file of Monit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the PID of the program to be able to monitor it with Monit. Some programs allow commandline arguments to give the location of a file that they are to write their PID to. Otherwise, you can try starting the program from a wrapper script that writes the PID to a known location, e.g. `/usr/bin/myprogram & && jobs -p > /var/run/myprogram.pid` in `bash`.

Comment: When trying to run what? What shell are you using?

Comment: terminal, I'm using linux ubuntu

Comment: i'm just replacing my file's name in the place myprogram in "/usr/bin/myprogram & && jobs -p > /var/run/myprogram.pid"  and given the command to create a PID file.

Comment: Check that your program really is in `/usr/bin` -- you might not need the full path anyway.

Comment: yeah it is!!
how I type is- " username:~# /usr/bin/myprogram & && jobs -p > /var/run/myprogram.pid "

Comment: hey, I have created the PID file what else I have to do, to run the C program using Monit

Comment: There's documentation and examples [here](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html).